# mixing video streams best practices

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer

I'm trying to implement a software that will mix up two usb camera video streams into a single frame (just like shown in the image).
I've been looking into GStreamer and Python/OpenCV, but I cannot find the best way of achieving my desired result since the computing power resources are very limited. Can this be done only using GStreamer? Is there any other alternative I can look up?

Please advice! Thank you!

[image: Example of what I try to achieve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a job for `videomixer` (runs on CPU) or `glvideomixer` if you have an OpenGL compatible GPU in that target machine.

Comment: I eventually went with this approach but with nvidia developed gstreamer plugins for better gpu acceleration. still marking this as an answer